# Fields on form, selected from data source are not available when using Me

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access

I have two fields on a form. Field 1 is auto number field named 5sID. Field 2 is a lookup field named 5sType.

When I open the VBA code for both the oncurrent and on open, I try to reference either field with a "Me.5sID" or "Me.5sType". In either case when I type in the "Me." the auto list shows the other eight fields in the table, but not these two.

I have used this for years on both datasheets or continuous forms. There are only the two fields on the form and they were selected from the table field list in the design view.

If I change the name on the Other tab of the property options, the fields then appear.

I have now rebuilt the table and the form, I have created a database and linked to the same table and still get the same results.

If I add another short text field it shows up when I type "Me." in VBA, but any other type of field does not show up.

Comment: Another interesting fact about this, if i change the name on the Other tab of the property options, the fields then appear.

Comment: I have now rebuilt the table and the form, I have created a database and linked to the same table and still get the same results.

Comment: If i add another short text field it shows up when I type "Me." in vba, But any other type of field does not show up

Answer (score 2):

Naming an identifier with a number as first character is a bad idea! Always start with a letter!

On Access 2013 that creates a compile error as the compiler expects a`=`as he interprets`.5`as a decimal-number.

That worked for you on older versions? Hard to believe!

As workaround use square-brackets like on identifiers containing spaces or other crap.

```vb
Me.[5sID]
```

or turn on`Show hidden Elements`in Object-Browser , what fixes Inteli-Sense and creates automatic brackets. Seems like this is a way to create hidden members ;)